# TextView Layout width Change

Tags: java, android

I want to change my TextView width from `wrap_content` to `match_parent` using java. Can anyone suggest a way to do it?

My current custom TextView is as below:

```
<com.example.app.mytext
                            android:padding="@dimen/lblTime"
                            android:id="@+id/text_quotes"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                            android:text="Text"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/newMainText" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting your TextView in your code :

`tv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`

Answer (score 0):

Just change this `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Comment: I want it using java...not using xml